# Enable Session ID logging in IIS

Tags: logging, iis

Is it possible to log only the SessionID in IIS log files? I've seen you can log the cookies info, which contains the sessionID, however this can log all cookies and the concern is that the IIS log files will grow considerably in size.

Thanks and regards,

Karthik

Answer (score 2):

By default, the SessionID is stored in a cookie, so you'll need to log all cookies to get the SessionID. You would have to go configure you website to use cookieless sessions which would force the SessionId to get passed in the URL. You can learn more on how to configure this at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725824(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Further to @PatrickBarron's suggestion, you need to log the value through the cookies collection, as IIS does not have direct access to the Session ID from the logging module.

In IIS navigate to the Site tree node, and select the Logging editor.  Click the 'Select Fields...' button and in the top part of the window, in Standard Fields, check the 'Cookies ( cs(Cookie) )' field.

Note that this logs the whole cookie, and not just the `ASP.NET_SessionID` value you're looking for.  Note also that not every session will have a SessionID as part of optimisations in ASP.NET.

If you want to be more granular than that I think you'll need to do something a bit tricky.  You could use UrlRewrite to extract the cookie value and write a new Request header, say `X-SessionID`, then add a Custom Field into the Logging? That's probably the shortest path; or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

SessionID is an application construct, which explains why it would not natively be logged by IIS.

You can try it by Response.AppendToLog method

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing around with this, and found cool work around. This will give you flexibility to put any value from response page.

STEP 1
Add to your code line that adds response.addHeader with desired variable
For example in ASP:
response.AddHeader "SERVER_SID",Session.SessionID

STEP 2
in IIS Manager select your site -> Select "Logging" configuration -> Click "Select Fields..." next to Format ("W3C" should be selected) -> In Custom Fields area click "Add Field..." -> in popup modal Enter the name for the filed, select "Source Type:" as "Response Header" and in the "Source:" field enter EXACT name of the header variable you entered in STEP 1. In our example it's "SERVER_SID". Click OK -> OK -> Apply

Now you should see it in your log file (BUT ONLY on the lines where actual request was made, not on images, JS files or CSS files)